# jqplot - format values on y-axis in the form of "1 mil, 2 mil, 3 mil" or "1k 2k 3k" instead of actual numbers

Tags: jqplot

Does anyone know how to do this?

Basically, I don't want to show on Y-axis the values like 100000, 200000, 300000 and so on.
They should be 10 K, 20 K, 30 K or "1 mil", 2 mil and so on.

Is there a way to do that in jqPlot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 tickFormatter = function (format, val) { 
 var number = val/1000;
 return number+"K";
}
```

And add this option to the plot:

```
axes: {
  yaxis: {
    tickOptions: {
      formatter: tickFormatter
    }
}
```

Comment: To problems here: 1.) you would format all axes like that potentially messing up small values on the xaxis.  2.) If double values get into the axes you'd be left with 1000.001 / 1000 = "1.000001K", good shortcut though instead of my verbosity.

Comment: Adding to your idea:
  tickFormatter = function (format, val) { 
    if (Math.abs(val) >= 1000000)
      return Math.floor(val / 1000000) + " M";
    else if (Math.abs(val) >= 1000)
      return Math.floor(val / 1000) + " K";
    else
      return val;
  }

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the situations that you pointed. I put values like 1.0001, 1000.0001. Still works. I only formatted the Y Axis. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do'h Sorry! I missed the yaxis format.  The Math.floor was to protect against jqplots auto-ticks returning doubles, they shouldn't do this for large numbers on the y-axis, but I've learned to never say never:  http://jsfiddle.net/3DB4N/6/

Comment: Yeap. If the values are all < 1000 occurs the problem that you pointed. The `Math.floor` thing is very interesting. BTW..why will the user want to put "k" if never reach that value?

Comment: Pabloker and Mark -- Thanks many tons..Truly appreciate your help -Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to use an axes `formatter`; something like:

```
  tickFormatter = function (format, val) { 
    if (val >= 110000)
      return "110K"    
    else if (val >= 100000)
      return "100K";
    else if (val >= 90000)
       return "20K";
    else if (val >= 80000)
       return "30K";   
    else if (val >= 70000)
      return "10K";
    else if (val >= 60000)
       return "20K";
    else if (val >= 50000)
       return "30K";
    else if (val >= 40000)
       return "30K";
    else if (val >= 30000)
       return "30K";    
    else if (val >= 20000)
       return "20K";
    else if (val >= 10000)
       return "10K";
    else
      return val;
  }
```

[image]

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3DB4N/1/).

Comment: Thanks so much Mark for taking time to help!